# Rasterio saving numpy array to GeoTiff with no need to change profile

Tags: python, rasterio, landsat

I am working with LandSat 8 data, calculating a vegetation index from a single scene. I can read the necessary bands and do the calculation. My issue occurs when I try to save the information back to a GeoTiff.

None of the spatial characteristics of the data have changed - same height, width, count (which is 1 for LandSat data files - each band is in its own file), crs, and transform.

And yet, when I save this back to a GeoTiff, the resulting code file only contains zeros.

To help folks reproduce this, below are some example cloud-optimized files:

```
cogs = ['s3://usgs-landsat/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2019/026/030/LC08_L2SP_026030_20190505_20200828_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_026030_20190505_20200828_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF',
 's3://usgs-landsat/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2019/026/030/LC08_L2SP_026030_20190505_20200828_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_026030_20190505_20200828_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF',
 's3://usgs-landsat/collection02/level-2/standard/oli-tirs/2019/026/030/LC08_L2SP_026030_20190505_20200828_02_T1/LC08_L2SP_026030_20190505_20200828_02_T1_QA_PIXEL.TIF']
```

Import needed packages

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.session import AWSSession
import boto3
```

Read in the data as variables

```
aws_session = AWSSession(boto3.Session(region_name='us-west-2'), requester_pays=True)
with rio.Env(aws_session,
            AWS_NO_SIGN_REQUEST='NO',
            GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN='TRUE'):
    with rio.open(cogs[0]) as src:
        profile = src.profile
        red_raw = src.read(1)
    with rio.open(cogs[1]) as src_nir:
        nir_raw = src_nir.read(1)
    with rio.open(cogs[2]) as src_qa:
        qa = src_qa.read(1)
```

Apply the data and cloud mask, scale the good quality data

```
cloud_free_vals = [21824, 21952, 22080, 22208, 23888, 24144, 30048, 30304,
       54596, 54724, 54852, 54980, 56660, 56916, 62820, 63076]
cloud_mask = np.isin(qa, cloud_free_vals)

red = np.ma.masked_equal(red_raw,0.0)
red = np.ma.array(red, mask=cloud_mask) 
red = red * 0.0000275 + -0.2
red[red>1] = 1
red[red<0] = 0

nir = nir_raw * 0.0000275 + -0.2
nir = np.ma.masked_less(nir, 0.0)
nir[nir>1] = 1

nirv = (nir-red)/(nir+red)*nir
```

When I plot the results, I get something reasonable
[masked LandSat data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZaDv.png).
But when I try and save the result as a geotiff to be accessed later (so that we preserve the geographical information - I have a lot of files to process!) I only end up saving a file full of zeros.
Here's the code I used to save the geotiff, using the profile saved from the red band file above.

```
save_example_file = rio.open(
    'test.tif',
    'w',
    **profile)
save_example_file.write(nirv.data, 1)
save_example_file.close()
```

Opening it again like so yields a field of zeros:

```
test2 = rio.open('test.tif', 'r')
plot_example = test2.read(1)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(plot2)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Which results in
[Bunch of zeros!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikmbb.png)